# Retraining CNN : Classification to Regression

Tags: regression, classification, image-processing, pre-training

I am currently working on CNNs and would like to create a Regression model. However I have a relatively small amount of new pictures so I was thinking about retraining. 
**Is it possible to retrain a classification model and turn it into a regression model?** I mean, is there a way to modify some layers at the end of the net to make it as a regression?

I do not really know if this was clear, I'll just try to show with an example :
Let's say you would like to **get the head position (x,y) on** dog **pictures**. Then you could retrain a CNN using dog pictures with (x,y) cooridnates as labels. 
Using retraining I expect that we will start using Weights and Biases already well initialized.

I tried to be clear, and welcome any kind of answer that can help me. I am also up to add further details if you need for better comprehension.

Thank you very much!